# Why is this *simple* KnockoutJS page not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I have been working with KnockoutJS for awhile and have about a dozen JQuery Mobile pages successfully working.  However, I just created a page that refuses to work correctly even though it is trivially simple. I thought I would strip the page down to its bare essentials and then build it back up until I found the problem...but the *bare essentials* aren't even working!

The HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="Content/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="A4LDistancePage">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Details</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            Minutes:
            <input id="DurMin" type="number" data-clear-btn="false" data-bind="value: DurationMin" title="Minutes">
            Seconds:
            <input id="DurSec" type="number" data-clear-btn="false" data-bind="value: DurationSec" title="Seconds">
            <div>
                Minutes:
                <span data-bind="html: DurationMin">0</span><br />
                Seconds:
                <span data-bind="html: DurationSec">0</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="A4LDistance.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The corresponding JS file is:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#A4LDistancePage', function () {
    function DistanceInfoFn() {
        var self = this;
        self.DurationMin = ko.observable(15);
        self.DurationSecs = ko.observable(1);
    }

    var dif = new DistanceInfoFn();
    ko.applyBindings(dif, $("#A4LDistancePage")[0]);
});
```

I declare the DistanceInfoFn this way because, in the full page, I also call a method on it before applying the bindings.

This page, as shown, *only binds the first input*.  The second input field and the two spans are never bound.  As I say, I have been doing this for months now and have never run into this kind of bizarre refusal to bind variables.  I could really use some help here as I have been banging on this and simplifying it for hours to see what is wrong and cannot see why it isn't working!

Comment: You sound frustrated, feel good :) Create a fiddle.

Comment: `self.DurationSecs` vs. `data-bind="value: DurationSec"` ... you have an extra `s` and by the way you should see a  binding error in your browser's console...

Comment: nemesv - I thought that I would see such an error in the Javascript debugging window but didn't. So I learned *another* thing today: always check the console window when having trouble with KnockoutJS.  This is why I love StackOverflow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DurationSec
```

should be

```
DurationSecs
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HWD6P/

I removed the jquery just because I wasn't using it in the example.

Comment: Sheesh - sorry about that one. Sometimes you look at something for *so* long that obvious stuff slips by.  But I did learn something: when a binding is mis-named then all bindings after it will stop working as well.